# Express route not getting called

Tags: express

I need to GET /system/school/add route and I have following calls in routes/system.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET /system page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('a');
});


/* GET /system/school/add page. */
router.get('/school/add', function(req, res) {
    console.log('b');
});


/* GET /system/school page. */
router.get('/school', function(req, res) {
   console.log('c');
});


module.exports = router;
```

and this is code that I have in app.js:

```
var system = require('./routes/system');
app.use('/system', system);
```

Still, /system/school/add is not getting called. Why is that?

Comment: GET /school/add will work, why are you assuming /system/school/add

Comment: because app.use adds /system in front of using routes from system.js

Comment: I'm sorry, I got to why is it working, I was trying to GET /school/add

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
app.use('/sustav', sustav);
```

with

```
app.use('/system', sustav);
```

This should work

Comment: Huh, sorry, I forgot to edit that line - it was in Croatian, now I edited it how it looks like.